# How to generate SWIG interface from C++?

Tags: java, c++, swig

Is there any way generate [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/index.php) interface from existing C++ code, if I want to expose everything one-to-one for my Java application?

To clarify, this is 3rd-party library and I don't have headers for top level files to generate interface from them.

Comment: So it sounds like you're trying to use a 3rd party C++ library in a Java application? Is there no Java library equivalent or way to write your application in C++?

Comment: @Avery unfortunately, I have an application written in Java and there are performance issues with alternative libraries written in Java. That is why I'm trying to optimize it with C++ library and don't want to go through routine process of writing swig interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have access to the header files, your only option is libraries that directly introspect the C++-based binaries. I would start by taking a look at JNA: it is the java equivalent of lua's libffi and python's ctypes. Since you need C++, look then at BridJ, nativelibs4java and JNAerator. I haven't used any so can't comment on their robustness or power.